# Euclidean Geometry Question: Show points $O$, $D$, and $A$ lie on a circle centered at $E$…

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

A friend asked me this question yesterday and I have no idea how to approach it other than resorting to coordinates. Let $\Gamma$ be a circle centered around point $O$. Choose any two points, $A$ and $B$ on $\Gamma$. Let $\alpha$ be the circle centered at $A$ containing point $B$, and let $\beta$ be the circle centered at $B$ containing point $A$. Let $C$ be the second intersection of $\beta$ with $\Gamma$, and let $D$ be either of the two intersections between $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Let point $E$ be the second intersection of line $\overline{CD}$ with circle $\Gamma$. Show that $O$, $D$, and $A$ all lie on a circle centered at $E$. I tried inverting everything with respect to circle $\Gamma$ but I'm afraid I'm still stuck.

[image]

Comment: Very interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First notice that $\triangle ABD $ is equilateral. Thus, all its angles are $60^\circ $ This gives the peripheral angle $\angle ACD=\angle ACE=30^\circ $. Thus, the central angle $\angle AOE=60^\circ $, i.e. $\triangle AOE $ is equilateral too. This proves that the circle centered in $E $ that passes through $O $ passes through $A $ as well.

What remains to prove is that this circle passes through $D $. For that, note that $\triangle OAD $ is congruent to $\triangle OBD $ (all corresponding sides equal), and $\angle ADB=60^\circ $. This allows us to calculate $\angle ADO=\frac {1}{2}(360^\circ-\angle ADB) =150^\circ $. As we know the central angle $\angle OEA=60^\circ $, this proves that $D $ is on the same circle.